# Webistrano on Windows

Tags: windows, ruby, webistrano

Has anyone had any success in getting Webistrano running on Windows.  Everywhere I have read says it wont run on Windows, but isnt that kinda the point of using Ruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Ruby (and Python) if you don't avoid linux specific path names, functions, and libraries it's not going to work on windows.

A lot of ruby development is done for linux/mac without thought towards portability so you'll have a more difficult time getting tools that work in Windows.